# Tools and methods for localization of ASP.NET application needed

Tags: localization, translation, resx

We have a multilingual site that is currently using 2 languages, but with several others coming soon. The site is localized primarily by resx files, but with some localized data in a database.

We need to find some tools to manage localization of the site - something that picks up on changes in resx files so translators will only need to translate new or updated texts.

Any ideas or recommendations? We're also interested in any articles about the logistics of localization if anyone has some.

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching this area as we speak and I came across your post. I'm not sure if this is any help but in the past we used RCWinTrans for our localization. This was for mutiple C++/MFC products although it does support .Net . We would have a RCWinTrans project for each language/product we intended to support although you could have multiple languages in a single project. It kept track of state (i.e. not-translated, translated, changed, etc) and would allow us to export the strings to an excel spreadsheet which we could then send onto a translator. They would updated the spreadsheet and we would reimport the data.

Hope this helps, apologies if I'm on the wrong track and I'm teaching grandma to suck egss. I will be creating another thread today with a similar requirement to this btw, but with a few more snagettes - might be worth a look to see if I get any answers. Cheers, Roger

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to have all the localization data the database (or a localization database), this way one could build the localization tools/interface as part of the application and poyentially use it for many applications?

Comment: We started by having all localization in the database, but have moved it into resx files, as most of it is part of the application itself and therefore should be contained within the application. Of course there is still some of the /data/ that needs localizing, and this is still in the database.

We would really like to avoid having to build a localization tool ourselves, if we could find a good off the shelf product that supports resx files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **free** tool called **Resource Translation Helper** ( http://www.winking.be/resource-translation-helper )

1. Install it
2. Point it to your project directory
3. Export to excel (.xls)

Give the excel to your translaters and let them update the columns.

1. Import the updated xls file again

The tool creates also a file to map the resx translation to the excel rows. Don't remove that or you will not be able to import again.

Works very good, but backup your data before adjusting things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- You cant try to use this `Visual Studio` extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2676967b-0516-4f5f-b312-6873e2f9d219.
- It allows to export/import your project resources to/from excel and to add new cultures.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I would like to add http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html
Free tool for .NET resource files.
This directly edits the resource files, no need to ex-/import.